# If statement loops on click, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is something really simple that i'm missing here. I have a very simple event and a very simple handler:

```
$('#toggler').on('click',function(){
      if ($(this).hasClass('choose')) {
          $(this).removeClass('choose');
          $.ui.hint.turnOn();
      }
      else {
          $(this).addClass('choose');
          $.ui.hint.turnOff(); 
      }

    });
```

When I click on it, it basically loops, adding and removing classes constantly. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? 
Thanks.

EDIT: html:

```
        <div id="toggler">
            <a href="#" mode="normal">Вкл.</a>
            <div class="hint-switcher">
                <div class="hint-switcher-toggle"></div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" mode="choose">Выкл.</a>
        </div>
```

It's a simple switch that only uses css to change its state.

Comment: What is in `$.ui.hint.turnOff` and `$.ui.hint.turnOn`

Comment: .on('click',function(e){  e.preventDefault(); .......

Comment: @FabianCook Two methods that do not affect the class/target/etc.

Comment: First remove  $.ui.hint.turnOn(); and $.ui.hint.turnOff();  and see if it is working in that case.

Comment: @Tyagi Done, doesn't help :(

Comment: I could not reproduce this using the code you've provided. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zwGST/

Comment: @jcsanyi The user can click anywhere inside that div and the switch will shift to either left or right, that's convenient.

Comment: try changing the browser or clearing web cache. might b your latest code is not reflected on your local browser

Comment: @nainy You haven't provided any code that shows that functionality. Please provide a working example of the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Can you show your full jquery code i.e beginning from document ready function. I have checked the same, I couldn't able to reproduce your issues.

Comment: My guess is that `turnOn` and `turnOff` contain `trigger('click')`, which is causing the loop.

Comment: Good news is, I can't really reproduce it either via jsfiddle. Bad news is, it got more cryptic now, lol. And @Barmar no, there aren't any other triggers in those methods, they do not relate to the switch i'm doing in any way.

Comment: If they do not relate to the problem in any way, please remove them. Continue removing items until you can't remove anything else and still see the problem. Then show us everything you've got. At the moment, what you're showing us does not have a problem, so we're guessing.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found what the problem was. There was a `trigger('click')` in the other file in my project which I accidentally missed and which caused the problem. Thanks to everyone who helped, I appreciate it.

Comment: And how was that trigger being called from the click handler?

Comment: @jcsanyi it wasn't, there was a click handler on the parent of this element that triggered a click on the switch. Pretty stupid, but that's not my code, haha. That's why you avoid spaghetti code, can't wait to use angular.js in the future.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure about it. But you should pass necessary parameter to the function I guess. You are **using 'ui' object without passing it**. Just try this once.

```
$('#toggler').on('click',function(event,ui){
      if ($(this).hasClass('choose')) {
          $(this).removeClass('choose');
          $.ui.hint.turnOn(); // Problem lies in this line i think. if this doesn't work
      }
      else {
          $(this).addClass('choose');
          $.ui.hint.turnOff(); // here too.
      }

    });
```

Please ignore my suggestion if doesn't work.

Comment: No, that's not the case, I'm calling a static method from the ui namespace. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: This answer would be right if he did `$[ui]`. `$.ui` isn't using `ui` as a variable -- names after `.` in JS are literals, not variables.